# What is the etymology of 'slap-bang'.?

Tags: etymology

I read "*slap bang* in the middle of the debate".

Comment: Hello, sivacva. Have you done any research yourself?

Comment: etymology is the wrong word for your question. You mean origin.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably a variant of the apparently older and similar expression ***[smack bang](https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/62/messages/270.html)***:

> The OED points out that the verb "smack" can be used as an adverb to mean "With, or as with, a smack; suddenly and violently; slap. Also with down, through, etc.
>
> The quotations given to illustrate this sense are:
>
> 1782 COWPER Smack went the whip, round went the wheels. 1799 GEO. [IV] in Paget Papers He..tumbled..smack on his face. 1806 H. SIDDONS Smack comes a ball from the enemy and carries away his head. 1836 T. HOOK So away I went smack bang into a quaker's shop to buy myself a pair of gloves.
>
> As you can see, by 1836 "smack-bang" already existed, doubling the effect of "smack" on its own. (VSD)
>
> The OED shows also a further development of the adverbial sense, to mean "completely, entirely; directly," and this is the way I usually hear it used - for instance, to be *"smack in the middle of something,"*  or in the quotations cited:
>
> 1828 WHEWELL We have got a decision which is smack against us. 1857 A. MATHEWS The wind being smack in their teeth the greater part of the voyage. 1864 TYTLER [Cardan] made the bishop smack whole in twenty-four hours.
>   And these too can be doubled for emphasis, "smack-bang." - Baceseras.

(Phrase Finder)

Answer (score 0):

[Lexicallab.com](https://www.lexicallab.com/2017/10/phrase-of-the-day-slap-bang-in-the-middle/) in its 'Phrase of the day' – 'slap bang in the middle',  says in a rather defeatist way '[The origins are] anybody's guess'.

But there is quite a lot of evidence available.

[Grose's Classical Dictionary of the Vulgar Tongue: Revised and Corrected – 1823](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=LXMKAAAAIAAJ&pg=RA18-PA2&dq=%22slap+bang%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjgyKjEtZTmAhWpRBUIHYJpA3EQ6AEIODAC#v=onepage&q=%22slap%20bang%22&f=false) gives a reasonably early usage, as onomatopoeic noun and attributive:

> **Slap-bang Shop**. A petty cook's shop, where there is no credit given, but what is had must be paid for down with the ready slap-bang,
>   i. e. immediately. This is a common appellation for a night-cellar
>   frequented by thieves, and sometimes for a stage-coach or caravan.

[Slang: A Dictionary of the Turf, the Ring, the Pit, Or Bon-ton ... by John Bee – 1823](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=LXMKAAAAIAAJ&pg=RA18-PA2&dq=%22slap+bang%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjgyKjEtZTmAhWpRBUIHYJpA3EQ6AEIODAC#v=onepage&q=%22slap%20bang%22&f=false) (the whole title [slightly modified here] is worth reading!) contains the more obvious literal sense:

> **Slap-bang**: a blow from each hand. See *one-two*.

'The old one-two' is still a well known phrase, and there is the more modern 'double whammy'. The modern emphasiser / interjection 'bom-bom' is similar in most respects, but hasn't the same distribution (*'bom-bom in the middle').

[The Comic Almanack: An Ephemeris in Jest and Earnest – C Tilt, 1840](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=EW1HAQAAMAAJ&q=%22slap+bang%22&dq=%22slap+bang%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiO6t7VupTmAhXpVxUIHRmgAMoQ6AEIYzAJ) (though it seems to be quoting Thackeray in his 'History of the next French Revolution') shows an earlyish usage that is (probably!) adverbial. This may show a transition to what I'm labelling the prepositional-phrase-modifier usage we know today.

> [... helter skelter], skurry hurry, slap bang, whooping, screeching,
>   and hurraing, blue coats and red coats, bays and greys, horses, dogs,
>   donkeys, butchers, baroknights, dustmen, and blackguard boys, go
>   tearing, all together, over the common after two or three of the pack
>   that yowl loudest. Why all this is, I can't say ....

Comment: I have heard 'smack dab', although I think it is a little old-fashioned, and possibly mainly British.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Good stuff. By the way, Grose's example seems to contain a misprint: "a petty crook's shop" seems more likely than "petty cook's", don't you think? (Oh - and the link to John Bee goes to Grose again.)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes 'smack dab' sounds like what I would use, more so than 'slap bang'. But coincidentally I just heard someone on TV with a Caribbean accent use 'slap bang' [Death in Paradise E8S8](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=death-in-paradise-2011&episode=s08e08)